# Lowest score from multiple trials

Tags: python, random

Hi have this code that makes 4 groups until numbers 1-4, then rates them on how good they are:

```
import numpy
import math
import random
for i in range(3):
  # everything is in, see the indentation
  members=4
  n_groups =4
  participants=list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
  #print participants 
  random.shuffle(participants)

  with open('myfile1.txt','w') as tf:
      for i in range(n_groups):
          group = participants[i*members:(i+1)*members]
          for participant in group:
              tf.write(str(participant)+' ')
          tf.write('\n')

  with open('myfile1.txt','r') as tf:
      g = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in tf.readlines()]
      print(g)




  my_groups =g

  def get_rating(group):
      return len(set(group))

  for each_grp in my_groups:  
      print((get_rating(each_grp)))

  print(sum(len(set(x)) for x in my_groups))
```

This is the output:

```
    [[1, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2, 3], [2, 2, 1, 4], [4, 3, 1, 2]]
3
3
3
4
13
[[3, 4, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 3, 2], [3, 4, 4, 1]]
4
3
2
3
12
[[3, 2, 3, 1], [4, 2, 3, 3], [2, 4, 1, 2], [4, 4, 1, 1]]
3
3
3
2
11
```

The square brackets are the 4 groups, the 4 numbers below rate each group so (1,1,1,1) is very good as has the least changes, whereas (1,2,3,3) is less good as it has 3 different numbers. The final number just sums all the 4 numbers up.

I was wondering if there was a way to display the lowest score with the group combination with all the groups, in this case 11 after i run the trial, this would make it easier if i do more trials like 2000

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `min(my_groups, key=sum)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight refactoring of your code, by defining a `run()` function you get to factor out the number of runs and min of all the runs:

```
import random

def run(members, n_groups):
    participants = list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
    random.shuffle(participants)

    # Chunk up the participants
    my_groups = list(zip(*[iter(participants)]*members))
    print(my_groups)

    def get_rating(group):
        return len(set(group))

    # for each_grp in my_groups:
    #     print(get_rating(each_grp))

    score = sum(get_rating(g) for g in my_groups)
    print(score)
    return score

members = 4
n_groups = 4

print(min(run(members, n_groups) for _ in range(3)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4, 3, 3), (4, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 3, 1), (2, 2, 1, 2)]
11
[(4, 3, 3, 4), (1, 3, 1, 2), (4, 2, 1, 4), (1, 2, 2, 3)]
11
[(4, 1, 1, 2), (2, 4, 3, 4), (4, 3, 2, 3), (1, 2, 1, 3)]
12
11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
# let all group of groups be in one array called out

out = [
  [[1, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2, 3], [2, 2, 1, 4], [4, 3, 1, 2]],
  [[3, 4, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 3, 2], [3, 4, 4, 1]],
  [[3, 2, 3, 1], [4, 2, 3, 3], [2, 4, 1, 2], [4, 4, 1, 1]]
  ]

# for each group of groups, sum the lengths of it's subgroups lengths and choose the minimum

res = min(sum(len(set(x)) for x in y) for y in out)

print(res) # => 11
```

You can also use an outer variable to hold the minimum :

```
minimum = 16 # the max score is 16 with a group of 4-scored subgroups
for i in range(3):
    # ... some code
    # ... more code
    temp = sum(len(set(x)) for x in my_groups)
    if temp < minimum:
        minimum = temp
```

Comment: Nothing is less that `-1`, so `minimum` will just be `-1` at the end of your second example, perhaps you meant a very big number e.g. `float('inf')`

Comment: @AChampion You're right, how didn't I see that? maybe I'm more used to finding the maximums, thanks.